# how apply css transition to an element after ajax response?

Tags: ajax, css, transition

i have a html table with percentage width that contain some text. my ajax function change this content to another text with different length, but the `td` width will re-sizing directly after ajax response. how to apply `css3` transition property to column width for soft and animated column re-sizing?

my `css` code:

```
table  tr td{
    color:#00cf00;
    padding:2%;
    font-family:"Courier New";
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:3;
    transition:width 1s;
}
```

i think the transition property execute just on hover event.

Comment: Can you post your AJAX?

Comment: This didn't deserve a down vote just because it wasn't completely filled out yet.  Give the asker time to provide more information and receive an answer.  People are becoming too hasty with downvotes.

Comment: A minor addition to Deep Mehta's excellent comments - Also look at the '.done' function after the ajax call.http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: function run(func,element_id)
 {
 var url="<?php echo site_url().'/administration/';?>".concat(func);
 document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML="<span>Running...</span>";
 var element_id='#'.concat(element_id);
 $.ajax({
   url:url,
   success:function(result){$(element_id).html(result);if(result=="login_failed") {alert('Your session expired.');window.location="<?php echo site_url();?>"}}
   });
 }

Answer (score 1):

In ajax success function add the CSS class using $('#id').addClass("class name");